# Unpacking tuples in a python list comprehension (cannot use the *-operator)

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

I am trying to create a list based on another list, with the same values repeated 3 times consecutively.

At the moment, I am using:

```
>>> my_list = [ 1, 2 ]
>>> three_times = []
>>> for i in range( len( my_list ) ):
...   for j in range( 3 ):
...     three_times.append( my_list[ i ] )
...
>>> print three_times
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

But I would like to do it using a more Pythonic way, such as:

```
>>> my_list = [ 1, 2 ]
>>> three_times = []
>>> three_times = [ (value,) * 3 for value in my_list ]
>>> print(three_times)
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

However, I cannot find a way to unpack the tuples.

Something like `three_times = [ *( (value,) * 3 ) for value in my_list ]` would be perfect for unpacking the tuples but this is not a correct syntax.

Comment: I find this suboptimal approach Pythonic `sum([[i] * 3 for i in [1,2]], [])`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can't use `*` iterable unpacking in a list comprehension, that syntax is only available in calls, and in Python 3, when using assignments.

If you want to use a list comprehension, just put your `for` loops in series; you do want to access the values from `my_list` directly rather than generate indices though:

```
[v for v in my_list for _ in range(3)]
```

There are several other options too:

- Use [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to repeat the values, and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to concatenate those iterators back together: `chain.from_iterable(repeat(v, 3) for v in my_list)`. That produces an iterator, you can use `list()` on it to get a list again.
- Use `chain.from_iterable(zip(*([my_list] * 3)))` to create an iterator over the repeated values (the repeated list is [transposed into repeated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)). This is not nearly as readable, of course, but we could make it slightly less bad by using `repeat()` here too: `chain.from_iterable(zip(*repeat(my_list, 3)))`. Again, use `list()` to produce the same output as the list comprehension.

Comment: Any ideas why? Even in 2021, this is not possible and I don't see any ambiguities in such a syntax...

Comment: @karlosss: it was taken out of PEP 448, due to strong concerns over readability, see the [variations section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#variations).

Comment: @nyuszika7h: if you want to debate the decision, please take it to the [Python discussion board](https://discuss.python.org/) or a mailinglist. Comments here are to help manage questions and answers only.

Comment: That should be `[v[i] for v in my_list for i in range(3)]`, probably?

Comment: @GiulianoCollacchioni: No, because that would be the same as `my_list * 3`, the list series repeated, rather than each value repeated before the next value is repeated, so `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]` instead of the expected `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`. You can swap the `for` loop order to get one or the other, too (so `[v for _ in range(3) for v in my_list]`.

Comment: @karlosss: it is impossible because it **is** ambiguous. `*iterable` means "sequence of elements of iterable", but what type this sequence should be? So you have to use `[*iterable]` or `*iterable,` or `{*iterable_of_hashables}` or `{**mapping}`.

Answer (score 17):

Accepted answer is correct, but I made some efficiency tests, so sharing it for passers-by.

**Summary:** Use `chain.from_iterable` for ~x2 speed improvement over list comprehension. And use `np.repeat` for ~x6 speed improvement if you don't mind importing `numpy`, but **don't** use `np.repeat` if eventually converting back to `list`.

```py
In [1]: from itertools import chain
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: 
   ...: def nested_list_comprehension(seq, repeats):
   ...:     return [v for v in seq for _ in range(repeats)]
   ...: 
   ...: def chain_from_iterable_tuple(seq, repeats):
   ...:     return list(chain.from_iterable((v,) * repeats for v in seq))
   ...: 
   ...: def chain_from_iterable_list(seq, repeats):
   ...:     return list(chain.from_iterable([v] * repeats for v in seq))
   ...: 
   ...: def numpy_repeat_list(seq, repeats):
   ...:     return list(np.repeat(seq, repeats))
   ...: 
   ...: def numpy_repeat(seq, repeats):
   ...:     return np.repeat(seq, repeats)

In [2]: seq = list(range(1000))
   ...: repeats = 100

In [3]: assert (
   ...:     nested_list_comprehension(seq, repeats)
   ...:     == chain_from_iterable_tuple(seq, repeats)
   ...:     == chain_from_iterable_list(seq, repeats)
   ...:     == numpy_repeat_list(seq, repeats)
   ...: )

In [4]: %timeit nested_list_comprehension(seq, repeats)
   ...: %timeit chain_from_iterable_tuple(seq, repeats)
   ...: %timeit chain_from_iterable_list(seq, repeats)
   ...: %timeit numpy_repeat_list(seq, repeats)
   ...: %timeit numpy_repeat(seq, repeats)
1.53 ms ± 2.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
814 µs ± 3.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
842 µs ± 2.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
3.65 ms ± 22.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
268 µs ± 1.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```