# SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension. What is the issue?

Tags: python

I have following code

```
li = [[[1,2],[3,4]]]
min([*x[0] for x in li])
```

I expected to see

```
Output: 1
```

But what happened is

```
SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension
```

What is the problem?

Comment: you can only use unpacking (the `*` notation in function calls)

Comment: Always share the entire error message. Speaking of, what don't you understand from that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpacking tuples in a python list comprehension (cannot use the \*-operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279653/unpacking-tuples-in-a-python-list-comprehension-cannot-use-the-operator)

Comment: You are expecting that the syntax `*x[0] ...` would return the zero'th item in every sublist `x` inside `li`.

Answer (score 1):

Or Just point the first element:

```
li = [[[1,2],[3,4]]]
min([x[0] for x in li[0]])
```

Or iterate all the canonized lists:

```
min([x[0] for xs in li for x in xs])
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are looking for something like this:

```
li = [[[1,2],[3,4]]]
min(li[0], key=lambda x: x[0])
```

If you would like to receive a pair with the minimum first argument, just provide your own comparison function to `min` as `key`.