# Flat list of pairs returned by functions as oneliner

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a collection of functions `fns` and each function returns a pair of integers `[a,b]`. I need to call each function and join the result in one flat list. Without comprehensions, the code would look like this:

```py
res = []
for fn in fns:
    res += fn()
return res
```

The question is, can I write this as a oneliner? I had high hopes with `[*fn() for fn in fns]`, however Python unfortunately does not understand the unpack operator here and throws a syntax error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpacking tuples in a python list comprehension (cannot use the \*-operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279653/unpacking-tuples-in-a-python-list-comprehension-cannot-use-the-operator)

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The answer says to change the way the tuples are created, which is not possible here - I receive them as the inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a double comprehension to unpack your values:

```
res = [i for fn in fns for i in fn()]

# Same as:
res = []
for fn in fns:
    for i in fn():
        res += i
```

or use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
import itertools

res = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(fn() for fn in fns))
```

Demo:

```
def a():
    return (1, 2)

def b():
    return (3, 4)

def c():
    return (5, 6)

fns = [a, b, c]
res = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(fn() for fn in fns))
```

```
>>> res
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I tried the "simple" variant before, however I had the `for`s vice versa, `[i for i in fn() for fn in fns]`, which complains that `fn` is not defined...is it simple enough to explain why you need to swap them, which I find very counter-intuitive?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, apparently I understood multiple comprehension wrong from the very beginning.

Comment: You should read this (I know it's counterintuitive): https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639246/15239951

Answer (score 1):

A not so elegant way to do it, but still an one-liner, would be to use `sum()`:

```
result = sum([fn() for fn in fns], [])
```

As explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-function-python/), `sum` can take two parameters, the iterable and the start.

So, if you want to sum a list, for example `l = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, you call:

```
r = sum(l)
```

which is basically:

```
r = sum(l, 0)
```

where `0` is the start number to be added in sum.

The above is the shortcut for:

```
r = 0
for elem in l:
    r += elem
```

The same way works for lists. The one-liner in the beginning is the shortcut for your code. The empty list `[]` needs to be set, because otherwise `sum` will default that argument to `0`, which will throw an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

and that is because you cannot add a list to a number.

Comment: I tried `sum`, but without the second argument, and even when I see it now, I don't understand it...can you please explain why you need it?

Comment: Perfect, with the explanation it does not look that much inelegant actually. Though I still like the double comprehension `[i for fn in fns for i in fn()]` a bit more.